# Django 4 migrate error: c.releasepartition does not exist

Tags: django, migration, migrate

When trying to migrate, I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/..../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column c.relispartition does not exist
LINE 3:             CASE WHEN c.relispartition THEN 'p' WHEN c.relki...
                              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

After downgrading to the previous version of Django by running:

```
pip install Django==3.2.12
```

Everything works again.